# Is there a way to hide the loading spinner for server side row model in agGrid for react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using the server-side row model in agGrid. The default loader provided by agGrid is hiding the data when the data is being loaded or invalidated again. Can anyone please help me is there any props or API in agGrid to suppress/hide the default loading spinner?

Comment: Hi, If are using `^27.3.0` version, we can use `loadingCellRenderer` prop and return null in this component to not to show inline conventional loading text with spinner. But I suggest something like skeleton loader to represent the rows. Also we can use `gridApi?.showLoadingOverlay()` & `loadingOverlayComponent` to show custom loading spinner

Answer (score 0):

If are using `^27.3.0` version, we can use `loadingCellRenderer` prop and return null in this component to not to show inline conventional loading text with spinner. But I suggest something like skeleton loader to represent the rows. Also we can use `gridApi?.showLoadingOverlay()` & `loadingOverlayComponent` to show custom loading spinner